# Sublime Text 2 creating config.rb

Tags: sublimetext2, compass-sass, sass

Today, when saving an SCSS file, **Sublime Text 2** (Windows) creates a `config.rb` in the same directory. Strangely enough, this never happened before. I already have a `config.rb` in the root of my project that I'm using with Compass so another one just messes things up.

- What causes this and how can I avoid it?

I have checked with Process Monitor, and it is `sublime_text.exe` that creates the file.

Comment: This is interesting, I ran in to the same exact thing today, and I'm still struggling with finding a solution. When saving a .scss file, normally it would compile the .css files in to a css/ folder per my config file's direction.  However, it instead creates a brand new config file inside my scss/ folder and compiles all of the css inside of this same folder.

Comment: My config.rb is one step further up in the directory tree and my SCSS files do compile to the correct folder - still, pretty annoying. And strange that the problem appeared overnight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK - I think I solved it.

You (unfortunately) have to remove the 'LiveReload' package from Sublime. I can't tell you why it's causing the issue, but removing this package solved the problem for me. I even reinstalled it and the symptoms returned.

Edit: [Opened an issue on LiveReload repo](https://github.com/dz0ny/LiveReload-sublimetext2/issues/40)

Comment: Wow, spot on. This was extremely puzzling to me, so grateful that you figured it out.